# TinyMCE 5.0 JQUERY save editor content from multiple editors

Tags: php, tinymce

Good day,

I have a question.
I have a form that shows multiple tinyMCE editors.

```
<textarea class="editor" name="my_editabletext[234]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="my_editabletext[110]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="my_editabletext[544]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="my_editabletext[128]"></textarea>
```

Now these numbers {234, 110, 544, 128} refer to their corresponding database ID's.
For general forms I tend to use :

```
    'data': $("#text_form").serialize(),
```

But that does not work for TinyMCE.
Now I know that there is a way to get the TinyMCE content. But I do not know how to get the content somewhat corresponding with an ID.

Is this even possible?

I would like to have something like :

```
$array = array(
                    'my_editabletext'   =>  array(
                                                    234     =>      'Hi',
                                                    110     =>      'how',
                                                    554     =>      'are',
                                                    128     =>      'you?'
                                                )
            );
```

Not for a 100% what I was after since I wanted the Id's filled but doesn't matter.

> As suggested by **BCM** But now i have :
>
> ```
> var allTextArea = document.getElementsByClassName("tinymce_editor");
>
> var i;
> var storedcontent = [];
> for (i = 0; i < allTextArea.length; i++) {
>     content = tinyMCE.get(allTextArea[i].id).getContent();
>     console.log(allTextArea[i].id);
>     storedcontent[allTextArea[i].id] = content;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want get tiny mce content you can use:

```
//Get content of a specific editor
var content = tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent();
```

If you know this, you can try:

```
var allTextArea = document.getElementsByClassName("editor");

var i;
var arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < allTextArea.length; i++) {   
  content = tinyMCE.get(allTextArea[i].id).getContent();
  arr.push(content);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Now you have all tinyMce content in java script array.